# Sql Server Management Studio 2008 - Insert string with more than two lines

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms

I want to paste a string with more than two lines into a nvarchar(max) cell 
(right click a Table in Sql Server Management Studio 2008 --> Edit Rows).
Unfortunately only the the first line of the string is pasted into the cell.

I know, I could write a Insert/Update script for that, but it's not what I'm looking for. I need a quick way to paste some text into some cell.

Is there a way to achieve my goal?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've just tried in 2005 using Ctrl+Enter, Alt+Enter, Shit+Enter. To my suprise, none of those worked!! You might want to try them in 2008 though.

Comment: Shit+Enter? ;-) 
I've tried in 2008 too. Is not working as well.

Comment: I was about to say "write an SQL INSERT statement" when I realized that we also can't enter newlines in a SSMS query window. (Maybe i'm missing some fancy escape sequence here?)

Comment: @grimming yes it's possible (no need for escape sequence). however the result is not showing properly in the Grid, but if you switch to text (or access via code) is working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it isn't possible at the moment, but Microsoft is looking into it:

http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/415157/copy-paste-of-row-with-multi-line-text-in-management-studio-2008-results-in-corrupted-data